# Need with removing matching data from two different table

Tags: impala

Thank in advance for your help.

I have to tables table "ABC" which is centralized table and second is "XYZ" which is a GAP table which is generated by a script. Now i have to update my GAP script to exclude the data which is matching centralized table ABC and no other data should come from table "ABC"

I want a sciprt to exclude the data from centralized table which is matching with my GAP table.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your ask correctly then you should just be able to conduct a LEFT JOIN and then filter out where one of the join key fields is NULL in the GAP table. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM ABC
LEFT JOIN XYZ ON ABC.Column = XYZ.Column
WHERE XYZ.Column IS NULL;
```